# Which noun modifies the verb?

Tags: modifiers

Should I say

> Which cyberattacks pose a threat to your business?

OR

> Which cyberattacks pose threats to your business?

Comment: It depends. Are you talking about *the overall class of threat* known as cyberatacks, or are you talking about *individual threats* known as cyberattacks?

Comment: Your first example is fine. We understand that there is more than one cyberattack that can pose a threat. Btw, the noun "cyberattacks" is subject of the verb "pose", not a modifier of it.

Comment: You can just about read 'pose/s/d'posing a threat to' as a fixed expression, a synonym of 'threaten' etc.

Comment: The overall class of threat known as cyberattacks

Comment: It’s not clear how your question title relates to your question.

Answer (score 1):

If you’re talking to the CEO (or the COO or the CFO),
“Which cyberattacks pose a threat to your business?”,
because their understanding of cyberattacks might be limited to
“they’re a threat to the business” (Frankenstein: “Fire … bad!”) 
If you’re talking to the CIO (Chief Information Officer),
or somebody on the IT staff,
“Which cyberattacks pose threats to your business?”,
because they understand that cyberattacks pose a spectrum of threats, such as

- Denial of Service — shutting you down, so you can’t operate
- Theft of Confidential Information, which can

  - hurt you directly (or, at least, help a competitor)
    if it involves trade secret information
    that lets you do what you do at the price you do it, or
  - hurt you in terms of public relations,
    if they overtly steal confidential customer information
  - can also hurt you competitively,
    if they steal your customer information
    and use it to solicit your customers away from you
- Tampering with the integrity of your information

  - If this is done in a broad but shallow way,
    like changing your customers’ account balances by a few cents,
    it can damage your credibility
  - Something like tampering with your customers’ order data
    could cause you to deliver the wrong products to the wrong people
    at the wrong address at the wrong time
  - Large-scale corruption or erasure of operating data
    could cause a denial of service,
    whose duration depends on how good your backups are
    (and whether the attackers were able to compromise them)
- Stealing crypto keys could let the attackers send false messages
  signed by you, damaging your credibility
- Vandalizing your web site can be anything from a minor nuisance
  (and a public relations black eye) to a full-scale denial of service
- etc.